# Print a "tree" structure in JSP page

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, tree

I'm trying to print out a "tree" structure in my JSP page that looks something like this:

```
Root
 |
 |----Dependencies
 |        |----A
 |        |----B
 |        |----C
 |
 |----Dependents
          |----D
          |----E
```

I'm hoping that someone around here knows of some utility that would help me do my job (it can use any technology, just as long as I can insert it in my JSP page). The Root and the other variables are all Strings (A, B, C etc...).

I'm planning on using something like this: (I haven't written this yet, so I'm not sure if it'll work...)

```
public class DependencyTree 
{ 
  private String root; 
  private ArrayList<String> dependencies, dependents; 
}
```

Basically, root corresponds to "root" on my example above, and the two ArrayLists contain A, B, C and D, E respectively.

Comment: You say you don't have a tree data structure yet, so how do you represent this structure in memory? Some details on the structure you are currently using will be useful.

Comment: I'm planning on using something like this: (I haven't written this yet, so I'm not sure if it'll work...)


    public class DependencyTree
    {
      private String root;
      private ArrayList<String> dependencies, dependents;
    }

Basically, root corresponds to "root" on my example above, and the two ArrayLists contain A, B, C and D, E respectively.

Comment: And how would I include code in my comments? I can't figure that out... haha

Comment: Don't include code in comments; edit your original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using some javascript to render the tree in your JSP, **jsTree** is a jQuery component which supports JSON and XML data sources to populate a tree view:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/jstree-jquery-based-javascript-tree-component

**Edit**:  Here is some more specific information on getting started with the component:  http://www.jstree.com/documentation/core

Comment: Hi Mike,
Thanks for the link to jsTree, however, could you give me some pointers on getting started (like how to install it etc...)? The website documentation isn't that clear...

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, I'll give it a try!